# ipTables: How to improve the current set-up?

Tags: linux, ssh, firewall, iptables

It took a lot of time and digging to get my ipTables working fairly well.

*Current status*: 'Works' w/ a noticeable, reproducible (*almost unacceptable*) **delay on SSH** connections. This delay goes away as soon as ipTables is disabled. Please help, how can I fight off the *long list of potential attacks*, and also get my fast ssh back?

```
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
#DROP fragments (from a *different* tutorial, do I need this?)
-A INPUT -f -j DROP 
#DROP NEW NOT SYN
-A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP 
#DROP SYN-FIN SCANS     
-A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN -j DROP 
#DROP SYN-RST SCANS      
-A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
#DROP X-MAS SCANS       
-A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL FIN,URG,PSH -j DROP 
#DROP NMAP FIN SCAN      
-A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL FIN -j DROP 
#DROP NULL SCANS              
-A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP  
#DROP ALL/ALL SCANS            
-A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP               
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
#non-standard ssh port matches ssh config
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport x1x0 -j ACCEPT  
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j DROP
```

Thank you

EDIT:
I dug deeper and my ISP's nameservers and DNS look-up might be the problem:

Why would the SSH server be doing a DNS look-up, when I'm connecting as root@xxx.xx.xxx.x?

and / or

Can I fix this (if DNS look-up is the cause) w/ an adjustment to the ssh config, instead of messing with having to find out the ip of the ISP's nameservers?

Comment: What does `ssh -v` say?

Comment: OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
usage: ssh...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the hang is caused when you login then it is probably related to the sshd `UseDNS` configuration parameter. The default for this is `yes` so sshd does a lookup on your client's hostname and then checks that it maps back to the IP address that is is seeing on the inbound connection.

You'll probably find that you don't have a suitable DNS [PTR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) record for your client.

Try setting

`UseDNS no`

in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file then restart sshd.

Comment: Perfect, I should have looked there already, but I've been "smashing my head on the firewall" for way too long. THANKS lain!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic gist of what I am doing, https://gist.github.com/801684. It's commented and I've never seen any connection slowdowns. But, make sure you have console access before mucking with firewall rules :)

Comment: Thanks slillibri, I tried several variations on your udp related code and failed to get it working. In "a few months" your set-up might be a "gold-mine of info," but right now I need a format more like the one posted above.